# MultiValueDictKeyError thrown when saving paginated django formsets

Tags: django, pagination, formsets

I've deleted previous question on this, and post a new one because after making several simplifications, I made the code more concise in order to diminish the number of possible reasons (specifically, I've removed the regroup part)

I use Django endless pagination (Twitter-style) for rendering a Django formset table. All works fine, until I try to save user input and end up with `MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'form-10-id'"`. Please not that it's not "u'form-**0**-id'", it's **10** (ten), meaning that the problem is not caused by missing hidden fields.

The template:

```
<table>
       <thead>...
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       {% load el_pagination_tags %}
       {{ my_formset.management_form }}

       {% paginate my_formset %}    

       {% for form in my_formset %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                            {{ hidden }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
                   .... 
            </tr>               
        {% endfor %}    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

View that handles AJAX POST-request to save the data

```
def view_for_saving_input(request):
    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
    FormSet =  modelformset_factory(MyModel, form = MyModelForm, can_delete=False, extra = 0)
    my_formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    # Also tried  my_formset = FormSet(request.POST, queryset = qs)
    # no difference

    for form in my_formset: # MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'form-10-id'"
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return HttpResponse(True)
```

If I remove `{% paginate my_formset %}` from the template thus giving up endless pagination, everything works just fine. I tried to swap the lines `{% paginate my_formset %}` and `{{ my_formset.management_form }}`, but still no success (in this case Django throws a seemlingly justified `Missing management form` error.

Intuitively, the core reason is because pagination does not allow to render the tenth form, and clearly, Django cannot find the hidden fields. But I've got no idea how to fix it

Comment: Hey, did you advance on this? I am having the exact same issue! Cheers